# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule with 2 variables

Tags: rewrite-rules, regex

I need to create a rewrite rule that accepts 2 variables. I'm very new to this and am not sure If I'm even on the right track. If there is a better solution to what I'm trying to achieve, I'm open for suggestions.

The url should look like this: localhost/states/id/state-slug

Here is what I have:

```
function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {

add_rewrite_rule ( 'states/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)', 'index.php? 
state_id=$matches[1]', 'top' );

add_rewrite_rule ( 'states/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/state([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)', 
'index.php?state_id=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]', 'top' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule');
```

Using what I have, I'm able to get the first variable (state_id) but not the second (state).

Comment: Try with `&state=state$matches[2]`

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Are the post *slugs* in this format: `state{slug}`, e.g. `state-one`, `statetwo`, etc.? I.e. the slug always *starts* with the text `state`? If so, then the `&state=$matches[2]` in the second `add_rewrite_rule()` should be `&state=state$matches[2]`

Comment: If not, then the `/state([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)` should probably be just `/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)` so that it works with all slugs regardless the slug starts with the text "state" or not. I hope this helps you.

Comment: The format i'm looking for is localhost/states/id/state-name so something like localhost/states/18/new-york

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my previous comment?

Comment: I did try that. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of pulling my hair out I figured out the problem.

I needed to use the add_rewrite_tag() function to tell wordpress to allow my query vars.

```
function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {

add_rewrite_tag('%state_id%', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%state%', '([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)');
add_rewrite_rule ( 'states/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)', 'index.php? 
state_id=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]', 'top' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule');
```

Comment: I see. And please don't forget to mark your answer as correct ("accept" it) so that people know the question has an accepted solution.